# MacBook Pro - High CPU Under Low Workload

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, performance, big-sur, kernel

I've got the MacBook Pro 16" 2019 (2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9, AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4 GB). Since upgrading to macOS Big Sur, I've been experiencing an issue whereby the system will become unresponsive under very low workloads (e.g Mail, Firefox and Notion).

When the system is rendered un-responsive, the CPU process "kernel_task" consumes a large amount of usage. I understand that this issue occurs when the device is overheating, however, as you can see from the image below, the processor is running relatively cool.

I suspect the issue is related to my display (BenQ EW3270U 32 Inch 4K), because, once you disconnect the display (via USB-C) then the CPU workload is immediately dropped to workable conditions. I plug it back in again, and can return back to normal (until the issue repeats)

I have attempted to resolve the issue by following the below check-list (provided by Apple Support), but continue to have problems:

1. Check hard drive space
2. Install updates
3. Start up in safe mode
4. Reset the SMC
5. Reset NVRAM
6. Check for Wi-Fi congestion
7. Clear DNS for DHCP systems
8. Reset home folder permissions
9. Check for adware
10. Check date and time
11. Use Disk Utility to check the startup drive
12. Disconnect external devices
13. Check Memory Pressure in Activity Monitor
14. Reinstall macOS
15. Reformat then reinstall macOS
16. Check third-party memory

I've since been advised that my MacBook Pro will require service, however this is not possible immediately due to lockdown and work needs.

Does anyone know of solutions to resolve this issue?

[image: A screenshot showing a CPU usage panel where "kernel_task" is consuming 986.5% of usage, and the temperature is 62 degrees]

Comment: When was the last time it was stripped & cleaned? Running a 4k monitor off a laptop is always going to cause heating, which the system if it's not cooling fast enough just with the fans will force extra effort by ramping kernel-task. Windowserver itself looks pretty busy. The Radeon looks silent, so it's probably running all that on the Intel, which will push CPU temperatures.

Comment: Is your monitor plugged in on the left or on the right? Try USB-C Ports on the right if you can.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Thank you. That makes sense, considering I've been working from home for the last year - the device might have a build-up of dust from where it sits. I haven't managed to get inside yet. Just getting the back-panel off is incredibly hard, without damaging the base. So I'll take it to a store, when lockdown measures ease in the UK.

Comment: @X_841 - The monitor is plugged in via USB-C on the right-hand side.

Comment: I wish you good luck on that front, with Boris's announcement yesterday ;)

Comment: As an update, I've since placed my laptop vertically using a stand to increase air input, and only using the primary 4K monitor when at my desk. I've had no issues since.